# Растягивается страница при скроллинге до самого низа

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка.
На моем сайте [e-geek.ru](http://e-geek.ru) при скроллинге до самого низа, скролл не останавливается, но продолжает растягивать документ.

Вот обработчик скролла:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var origTop = $('#sidebar').offset().top;
  var origBottom = origTop + $('#sidebar').height();

  var scrollDir = 0;
  var scrollLast = 0;

  var weirdOffset = -8;

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    var curTop = $('#sidebar').offset().top;
    var curBottom = curTop + $('#sidebar').height();

    if(scrollTop > scrollLast) {
      scrollDir = 1;
    } else if(scrollTop < scrollLast) {
      scrollDir = 0;
    }
    scrollLast = scrollTop;

    if(scrollDir == 1) {
      if(scrollBottom >= origBottom && scrollBottom >= curBottom) {
        $('#sidebar').animate({
          top: scrollBottom -  $('#sidebar').outerHeight() + weirdOffset
        }, 0);
      }
    }

    if(scrollDir == 0) {
      if(scrollTop <= origTop) {

        $('#sidebar').css('top', (origTop + weirdOffset) + 'px');

      } else if(scrollTop <= curTop) {

        $('#sidebar').animate({
          top: scrollTop + weirdOffset
        }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Это потому что в боковой панели у вас снизу остается отступ, связанный со скрытым, но присутствующим в потоке элементом подсказки пункта меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Именно на величину этого пункта у вас прокручивается страница сверх нормы.

Решить можно тремя способами:

1. Задать для `#bx_sidebar` `overflow: hidden;` - но тогда ваша подсказка перестанет быть видна при ховере на пункт меню;
2. Показывать подсказку не под пунктом, а над пунктом, и задать ей `position: absolute;`;
3. Заменить такую подсказку на нативный и стабильно работающий атрибут `title` у пунктов меню.

Тогда проблема со скроллингом исчезнет.

Comment: Спасибо Виталий! Поставил бы + но не уитывают пока что мои)